# get the dropdown particular selected value and dispaly confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, smarty

I have member status select box in that i have open,read,close option is there.So when i'm selecting  open or read and click update button  it will updateing something.and i'm selecting close it display dialog box(Are you sure want close this)if yes it goes to some page or goes to no page.(I want to dispaly confirm box only particular value(22 only).
Anybody help on this one(js or jquery).It is smarty application

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function showClose() { 
            var val = document.getElementById('sel_state').value; 
            if (val == '22') { 
                var state = confirm("Are you sure want to change member status??"); 
                if (state == true) { 
                    alert('yes'); 
                } else { 
                    alert('no'); 
                } 
            } else { 
                alert('no'); 
            } 
        } 
    </script> 
</head>
<body> 
<form method="post" action="/admin/member-modify-{$member->id}">
    <label>Member state</label>    
    <select name="sel_state" class="validate" id="sel_state"> 
        <option value=1>open</option> 
        <option value=2>read</option> 
        <option value=22>close</option> 
    </select> 
    <input name="submit" value="Validate" id="member_state_submit" type="submit" class="submit" Onclick="showClose();" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showClose() {
  
 
var val=document.getElementById('sel_state').value;
if(val=='22'){
      var state= confirm("Are you sure want to change member status??");
        if(state == true){
           alert('yes');
}

else{
alert('no');
}
    
} 
else{
alert('no');
}

}
</script>
</head>

Comment: <body>
<form method="post" action="/admin/member-modify-{$member->id}"> 
<label>Member state</label>
<select name="sel_state" class="validate"  id="sel_state">
<option value=1>open</option>
<option value=2>read</option>
<option value=22>close</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" value="Validate" id="member_state_submit" type="submit" class="submit" Onclick="showClose();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

All what you have to do is to wrap your JS code within `{literal}{/literal}` tags like this :

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showClose() { 
        var val = document.getElementById('sel_state').value; 
        if (val=='22') { 
            var state = confirm ("Are you sure want to change member status??");
            if (state == true) { 
                alert('yes'); 
            } else { 
                alert('no'); 
            } 
        } else { 
            alert('no'); 
        } 
    } 
</script>
{/literal}
```

In Smarty, anything within `{literal}{/literal}` tags is not interpreted, but displayed as-is. This will avoid  interfering with the template delimiter syntax. Check the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal.tpl).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple with jquery

```
var value = $('#selector').text()
if (value == 22){
   //do something here
}
```

Comment: Done in same as java script but it is not working.Could you please  explain more clearly

Comment: you are using select box so use `val()` if you need value or use `text()` if you need text of option

Comment: I added jquery like this

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#member_state_submit').click(function(){
    
var value = $('#sel_state').value();
if (value == 22){
   var result = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
   if(result){
       alert('yes');
        }
        else{
            alert('no;')
        }
}
});
        });